Cypress: Prepare HttpProgressEvent
In Cypress, I'm able to intercept HTTP call and return arbitrary HttpResponse by using intercept command:
cy.intercept("POST", 'some/url', {
  statusCode: 200,
  // etc.
});

Is it possible to similarly prepare response in a form of HttpProgressEvent?
I developed file upload using this tutorial, specifically
const req = new HttpRequest('GET', 'someUrl, {
  reportProgress: true
});
this.http.request(req)
  .subscribe(...);  //here all the handling stuff is located

and since the file is quite large, I'd like to see some loading marker in the UI and also to test, that it is displayed, using Cypress.

For an e2e test, you would query the marker in the UI with a cy.get() query.
To make sure the progress is not too fast for the test, or is consistently slow enough for the the test to see the marker, you would use a throttle on the cy.intercept for example Throttle or delay response all incoming responses.
// Throttle API responses to simulate real-world conditions
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept(
    {
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/**',
      middleware: true,
    },
    (req) => {
      req.on('response', (res) => {
        // Throttle the response to 1 Mbps to simulate a
        // mobile 3G connection
        res.setThrottle(1000)
      })
    }
  )
})


My testing file is really small, so instead of throttling I used res.setDelay() to make sure Cypress will notice the progress state.

If you want to log the progress events to the Cypress runner, you would use Cypress.emit() to send the event from the app to the Cypress.
The currently running Cypress instance is attached to the window object of the app.
It would be something like this:
In the app
this.http.request(req)
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (window.Cypress) {
      window.Cypress.emit('app:http:progress', data.progress)   // send progress info
    }
  })

In the test, you can listen to this event the same as any internal Cypress event
const progressHandler = (ev) => {
  Cypress.log({
    displayName: 'http:progress', 
    message: `${ev.progress} %`
  })
}
Cypress.on('app:http:progress', progressHandler)

cy.intercept(...).as('loading')

// trigger the loading...

cy.wait('@loading')
  .then(({request, response}) => {

    // turn off the progress logger
    Cypress.off('app:http:progress', progressHandler)

    // assertions after the load is complete
  })

